# Two word alias in zsh

Tags: alias, zsh

It's easy to do a one word alias in ZSH.

```
alias ll='ls -lah'
```

Is there a way to do two word aliases with Zsh, so that both words are parsed as part of the same alias? I'd mostly like to use it for typo fixes.

```
alias 'gits t'='git st'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
alias func='gits t'
func() {
    'gits t'='git st'
}
```

more info here about **Zsh** alias functions:

- http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Aliasing

Comment: Ugh, this is not working for me any more... Either says "gits: command not found" or gits:1: gits t=git st command not found

Comment: That's because it has never done what you want, but rather did something else, and isn't a correct answer.  Since version 5.4.2 it has been an error by default.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/607909/5132

Answer (score 4):

The same as in plain bash:

```
$ cd
$ vim .zshrc
```

```
...
tg() {
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        echo "Use correct second argument: apply/destroy/plan/etc"
    else
        if [ "$1" = "0all" ]; then
            terragrunt destroy -auto-approve && terragrunt apply -auto-approve
        elif [ "$1" = "0apply" ]; then
            terragrunt apply -auto-approve
        elif [ "$1" = "0destroy" ]; then
            terragrunt destroy -auto-approve
        else
            terragrunt "$@"
        fi
    fi
}
...
```

Don't forget to reread file:

```
$ source .zshrc
```

And after use e.g.:

```
$ tg 0apply
```